# Perspective Translation Of Quadrilateral

Tags: perspective, 2d-graphics

I have mapped four rectangular point(R1->R4) to four quadrilateral points(Q1->Q4) to generate a perspective view.
Now I have to translate quadrilateral in x and y direction while maintaing perspective view. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The standard approach is to use a transformation $T$ that does the conversion form space to space. In this case Homogeneous coordinates could be used. The process is pretty well described [here](http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/building-basic-perspective-projection-matrix). Feel free to write a proper answer so that the question wont hang here forever.